# higher Eilenberg-Moore-toposes of left exact derived comonads

Tags: infinity-topos-theory

It is a classical fact (e.g. [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos+of+algebras+over+a+monad#ToposProperty)) that for an (accessible) right adjoint comonad on a (sheaf) topos, its Eilenberg-Moore category of coalgebras is itself a (sheaf) topos.

I suppose this remains true for $\infty$-toposes, for hypercomplete $\infty$-stack $\infty$-toposes at least? (But not assuming that the comonad is idempotent.)

Comment: Do you know that the forgetful functor from coalgebras preserves and reflects colimits and pullbacks? If so, the characterization of ∞-topoi by descent (prop 3 [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2C1%29-topos)) immediately implies that coalgebras form an ∞-topos.

Comment: Thanks. You mean "do you know if" rather than "do you know that", right? Am in a rush now, will check later.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant. The reflection part follows from conservativity of the forgetful functor, which is left adjoint, so I think the only thing to check is the preservation of pullbacks.

Comment: maybe with section 6.3 of Riehl-Verity 13 http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/(infinity,1)-monad#RiehlVerity13 Unfortunately, I am still in a rush now to receive a guest, will come back to this a little later.

Comment: Indeed, Theorem 6.3.8 does the trick! So coalgebras satisfy descent, but do they form an accessible ∞-category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E$ is an ∞-topos and $T: E \to E$ is an accessible left exact comonad, then indeed the ∞-category $E^T$ of $T$-coalgebras is an ∞-topos. Moreover, it is hypercomplete if $E$ is. I will first show:

> **Lemma.** Let $E'$ be presentable and let $U:E'\to E$ be a conservative functor that preserves colimits and pullbacks. Then $E'$ is an ∞-topos.

Proof. Recall that a presentable ∞-category $E'$ is an ∞-topos iff it satisfies descent, which means the following: If $a,b: K^\triangleright \to E'$ are cones, $\phi: a \Rightarrow b$ is a natural transformation, $b$ is a colimit, and $\phi$ is cartesian on $K$, then $a$ is a colimit iff $\phi$ is cartesian. In our situation, by the hypotheses on $U$, $a$ is a colimit iff $Ua$ is a colimit iff $U\phi$ is cartesian iff $\phi$ is cartesian. //

If $T$ is an accessible comonad on $E$, $E^T$ is accessible since it can be written as a limit of accessible ∞-categories. Moreover, the forgetful functor $U: E^T\to E$ creates colimits and is conservative ([1] 3.2.2.5 and 3.2.2.6). If $T$ is left exact, then $U$ is also left exact ([2] Corollary 5.5).

So the lemma implies that $E^T$ is an ∞-topos. Moreover, the forgetful functor $U$ is the left adjoint of a geometric morphism. Since $U$ preserves connectivity and is conservative, $E'$ is hypercomplete if $E$ is.

[1] J. Lurie, [Higher Algebra](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/higheralgebra.pdf)

[2] E. Riehl and D. Verity, [Completeness results for quasi-categories of algebras, homotopy limits, and related general constructions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.6247v3.pdf)